# How to add integers in a 2D array when the indexes are already initialized?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, sum

How do I add the values of a 2D array in java if all the values are initialized? For example:

```java
int[][] numbers = {{1, 2, 5}, {10, 3, 8}};
```

I was thinking about using a double for loop but I don't know how to refer to the rows and columns of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested loops to access the elements of 2D array.

Sample code to access the elements in numbers array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    int rowSum = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
        rowSum = rowSum + numbers[i][j];
    }
    System.out.println("Sum of elements in row " + (i+1) + " is:" + rowSum);
}
```

Here `rows` is the total number of rows in the array i.e. 2 and `cols` is the total number of columns in the array i.e. 3.
`numbers[i][j]` represents the element at row with index `i` and column with index `j`.

You can think of your array as shown in the table:

[image: 2D array as a table along with indices]

***Note: Indexing is 0-based in java for arrays. That's why i and j are starting from 0 to n-1 (n is size of either row or column)***